# Making Linear Layout background transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make the Linear layout's background transparent?

[image: My app image]

I want to make the area around the share button transparent. I have tried various solutions like

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

and

```
android:alpha="0"
```

and many other solutions but none of these seems working.
How can I make this area transparent over the image and other elements?
I have also tried the Frame Layout but it also doesn't work.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
    tools:context=".ReadMoreActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/readMoreImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/readMoreTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Card Title"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/readMoreDesc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="Card description"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:text="Share"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#9C27B0"
                app:strokeColor="#9C27B0"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do You want a spiderman to be a background on full screen and a button on the bottom which will be on transparent LinearLayout?

Comment: I just want all the white area around share button to be transparent.

Comment: I think You have pasted incompleted code. When I paste this code to AS and set background to the Root container, Linear Layout is transparent.  I think it is hard to recreate the Image layout with code. Do You want Your final layout to look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/zfZ1vk0.png)?

Comment: @iknow Actually  its like a blog post first there is image then title then description all fetched from firebase. Its all in scroll view and I want a static button at end of screen which sticks there and we can scroll rest of the screen. For this I have have used layout inside layout but as you can see that white area around share button ruins it all please help me.

Comment: I have added an answer, check it, and let me know if it is what You wanted to do. If yes feel free to accept and upvote :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestood You correclty You can do it like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/readMoreTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Card Title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/readMoreDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:text="@string/long_card_desc"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                >

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#880E4F"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#FFF9C4"
        app:cornerRadius="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="#006064"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now Button sticks to the bottom of the screen and You can scroll the content.
Result (left with a scrolled view and right starter look):

[image]

Comment: thanks you saved me bro/sis !!! and one more thing app:cornerRadius="xdp" is not working in your solution how can I edit that as well.

Comment: To what view You want to apply `cornerRadius`?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Now You can apply radius to the button. You couldn't do it before because You have set `background` attribute and I just copied Your button.

Comment: thanks for the solution. Do you know how get better these designing concepts?

Comment: You are welcome. It's hard to tell, I am also very new to Material Design but You can check [here](https://material.io/components).